# pysimpleguiで複数のFrameを上揃えにする方法

Tags: python

https://mebee.info/2022/02/04/post-34359/
上記のサイトを参考に、複数のFrameからなるlayoutを作成しました。

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('LightGreen')
l1 = [      
        [sg.Button('A',size=(5,1)),sg.Button('B',size=(5,1))],
        [sg.Button('C',size=(5,1)),sg.Button('D',size=(5,1))],
        [sg.Button('E',size=(5,1)),sg.Button('F',size=(5,1))],
        [sg.Button('E',size=(5,1)),sg.Button('F',size=(5,1))],
        [sg.Button('E',size=(5,1)),sg.Button('F',size=(5,1))],
        [sg.Button('E',size=(5,1)),sg.Button('F',size=(5,1))]
    ]

l2 = [        
        [sg.Button('A',size=(5,1)),sg.Button('B',size=(5,1))],
        [sg.Button('C',size=(5,1)),sg.Button('D',size=(5,1))]
    ]

layout=[[sg.Frame('Group 1',l1),sg.Frame('Group 2',l2)]]

window = sg.Window('title', layout, size=(300, 300))
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
```

各フレームの要素数が異なる場合に、中央揃えされてしまう問題があり、
上揃えにする良い方法はあるでしょうか？

一つの方法としてpadをそれぞれ指定することもできるかと思いますが、
上下左右を全て位置を計算して指定するのはやや煩雑で、より良いメソッドがあれば教えてください。
https://mebee.info/2022/01/01/post-34174/

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout= の次の行に以下の一文を追加してみてはどうでしょうか

```
layout[0][1].VerticalAlignment = "top"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。これで対応できそうです。